# yum downloadonly does not get all rpms needed for network free upgrade

Tags: yum, fedora

I need a method to install all the rpms and their dependencies that this client needs to get a php app running.  The client does not want to connect their fedora server to the internet. I tried doing yum install --downloadonly and then installing these rpms.  And thought it downloaded all the needed dependencies. However when I tried to rpm -Uvh *.rpm it complained that It could not install the rpms because other rpms needed those. the error would look like this.

```
>--> Finished Dependency Resolution
>Error: Package: rpm-python-4.11.2-2.fc19.x86_64 (/rpm-python-4.11.2-2.fc19.x86_64)
>           Requires: rpm = 4.11.2-2.fc19
>           Installed: rpm-4.11.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64 (@anaconda)
>               rpm = 4.11.0.1-2.fc19
>           Available: rpm-4.11.3-1.fc19.x86_64 (updates)
>               rpm = 4.11.3-1.fc19
>Error: Package: rpm-build-libs-4.11.2-2.fc19.x86_64 (/rpm-build-libs-4.11.2-2.fc19.x86_64)
>           Requires: rpm-libs(x86-64) = 4.11.2-2.fc19
>           Installed: rpm-libs-4.11.0.1-2.fc19.x86_64 (@anaconda)
>               rpm-libs(x86-64) = 4.11.0.1-2.fc19
>           Available: rpm-libs-4.11.3-1.fc19.x86_64 (updates)
>               rpm-libs(x86-64) = 4.11.3-1.fc19
```

Any suggestions on how to get these dependencies too.

Comment: Look at the _complete_ package list. Also, it's obvious that that server has already been connected to the Internet and is capable of receiving updates.

Comment: Going this route is more of a pain than it's worth IMHO.  It's far easier to use rsync to mirror the yum repo and create a [local mirror](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Infrastructure/Mirroring#How_can_someone_make_a_private_mirror.3F).

Comment: Try running `yum localupdate *.rpm` instead of `rpm -Uvh *.rpm`. Does that work any better?

Answer (score 0):

If your client doesn't want to give their Fedora server internet access to download updates, the server is most likely completely unpatched. Downloading RPM's using a server that is internet connected may result in downloading RPM packages have been updated since the original Fedora release and that are dependent on already installed updates as well, which will result in errors when trying to install them offline.

The easiest is often to use the original install medium as the yum repository for offline systems. As far as I know the installation CD/DVD is already a fully fledged repository. I don't have a Fedora install available now, there may already be a `cdrom` repository available, otherwise set one up with :

```
#/etc/yum.repos.d/cdrom.repo
[cdrom]
name=Local CD Repo
baseurl=file:///mnt/cdrom
```

Insert and mount the install DVD on /mnt/cdrom and run `yum --enable-repo=cdrom install <package>`